# One user account not working correctly

Tags: macos, mac, mouse

I am running OSX 10.7.5 on an iMac 3.06GHz Core 2 Duo Processor.  I have 3 user accounts.  2 are admin.   one of the Admin accounts has gone nuts.  The other 2 user accounts work just fine in every way.

The account that is nuts now: I can login.  I can open a window using the mouse or the keyboard but the mouse does not work in the body of the window.  The mouse will click on toolbar at the top of the page and any pull down menu items but not work to click on the red, yellow or green circle to close the window or drag the window, etc.

I repaired disk permissions, I ran file repair, I have restarted several times, I have pinged the prams (or whatever it's called now)

I need the files from that user account!!  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just need file access but don't need to be able to log in as that user you could just change the file permissions of the nutty users home folder.

Logged in as admin navigate in the Finder to the nutty user's home folder.

Select a folder you would like to be able to access (Desktop... Documents etc) and Get Info on it (Command + I).

In the resulting Info window in the "Sharing & Permissions" section hit the plus button and select the group "Administrators" (or a named user if you prefer) and give this group (or named user) "Read only" access (or Read & Write if you prefer).   Then under the little gear select "Apply to enclosed items"

Repeat for each folder you want to access.

Comment: Thank you.  I will definitely try this. Only problem is,  I am not sure exactly where everything is.  We did a lot of VHS to DVD conversions from old home movies and they are all there somewhere but I am not sure where.  Do you know where all the user files are stored?  Do they have a certain file name?  I need to go thru all the emails and save the relevant ones also. Is there anyway to reset that account?  I know just enough about this stuff to be dangerous at this point in time.

Comment: Oh and I can log into the account with no problem.  It just does not recognize the mouse for anything other than the tool bar menus so impossible to navigate once I am in.